# Количество модераторских тревог не обновляется само

Tags: предложение, инструменты-модератора

Кнопки в хэдере, а именно сообщения и достижения, периодически сами обновляются, чтобы отражать текущую ситуацию. Однако с сообщениями и тревогами модератора этого не происходит. Хотелось бы, чтобы эти два значка тоже обновлялись на открытой странице.

[image: скриншот]